# wrapping text on circular textpath

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am building a [chart](https://codepen.io/bumbeishvili/pen/EKJOmE) using `D3.js`, which shows some info about employee's competencies.

screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, some text is larger than container element size, because of that, part of the text, is cut.  I want to wrap these texts inside container.

I found [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321)  , but I was not able to apply some solution to my chart.

Help would be appreciated...

Here is [charts codepen url](https://codepen.io/bumbeishvili/pen/EKJOmE)
and here is [full screen view](https://s.codepen.io/bumbeishvili/debug/EKJOmE?editors=0010)

p.s. I need text to be wrapped by words

Comment: Do you want to wrap by words or by letters? (in case a word does not fit within the available space)

Comment: I wanted by words, but from now , I think , it  not will be  hard to to transform your solution, to fit my needs

Comment: hmm... It was hard  :s

Comment: no , I did not succeed

Answer (score 2):

In order to wrap the labels, you need to adjust Mike's solution to deal with `textPath` elements.

For this, we need several things:

**1. Get the available width, reaching which the labels should wrap**

You could compute the length of the arc itself, but I've done this by computing the segment created by the endpoints of your invisible paths that your labels follow. This will provide us with a little side margin as well, as the segment's length is shorter than the arc's length.

The distance between two points is computed as follows:

`d = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)`

**2. Wrap the labels when they rich available width and keep the aligned to center**

For managing this one, I had to dig into the `SVG` documentation on the [`textPath` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextPathElement) to see how it can be wrapped and shifted along the y axis.

Initially, I tried setting several `textPath` elements within one `text` label, but I couldn't manage to shift them along the y axis. It turns out, that for this you need to add `tspan` elements within `textPath` elements. But here another problem arose - I couldn't manage to keep them centrally aligned.

In the end, to achieve shift along y axis and central alignment, you need to use one `textPath` element (for horizontal alignment) with one `tspan` element inside (for vertical alignment).

**3. Wrap the labels by letters, not by words**

This is the point that I have assumed that you'll need namely letter wrapping (at the moment of writing, I didn't get the answer from OP), because on small sizes of your chart, there are words too long to fit into one line.

This was the easiest problem to solve. Just adjust the splitting and joining operations to switch from words to letters:

```
letters = text.text().split('').reverse();  // instead of .split(/\s+/)
...
tspan.text(line.join(""));  // instead of .join(" ")
```

And here's the whole code that was changed, with relevant comments:

```
outerSvg.selectAll(".outerCircleText")
  .data(pie(behaviorsDatasetOuterCircle))
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "outerCircleText")
  //Move the labels below the arcs for those slices with an end angle greater than 90 degrees
  .attr("dy", function (d, i) {
      d.i = i;
      return (d.startAngle >= 90 * Math.PI / 180 ? 18 : -11);
  })
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; })
  .call(wrap);  // Do not add `textPath` elements here. Instead, add them in the `wrap` function

function wrap(text) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        letters = text.text().split('').reverse(),
        letter,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        textPath = text.text(null).append("textPath") // Add a textPath element
            .attr("startOffset", '50%')
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#outerArc" + d.i; }),
        tspan = textPath.append('tspan'), // Inslide textPath, add a tspan element, for offset feature later.
        path = d3.select(text.select('textPath').attr('xlink:href')); // Get the path to compute width of text later.
    
    var startLoc = /M(.*?)A/;
    var newStart = path.attr('d').match(startLoc)[1];
    var newEnd = path.attr('d').indexOf(' 0 0 0 ') > -1 
        ? path.attr('d').split(' 0 0 0 ')[1] 
        : path.attr('d').split(' 0 0 1 ')[1] ;
    
    // Compute the start/end coordinate points of the arc that the text will follow.
    var x1 = parseFloat(newStart.split(' ')[0]),
        y1 = parseFloat(newStart.split(' ')[1]),
        x2 = parseFloat(newEnd.split(' ')[0]),
        y2 = parseFloat(newEnd.split(' ')[1]);
    
    // Compute the length of the segment between the arc start/end points. This will be the
    // width which the labels should wrap when reaching it.
    var width = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2));
    
    // And then we go on (with slight changes) with the example from Mike Bostock 
    // from here https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321
    while (letter = letters.pop()) {
      line.push(letter);
      tspan.text(line.join(""));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(""));
        line = [letter];

        // Instead of adding only a tspan element, add a new textPath so that the wrapped 
        // letters will be aligned to center. Without it, the letters will start drawing 
        // from right with part of them invisible, like if the labels are not wrapped. 
        textPath = text.append("textPath")
            .attr("startOffset", '50%')
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#outerArc" + d.i; }),
          
        // Add a tspan element to offset the wrapped letters from the previous line
        tspan = textPath.append("tspan")
            .attr('dy', '1em')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .text(letter);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

In the end, it was an interesting challenge. [Here](https://codepen.io/iulian4ik/pen/jqRJmM) is a fork of your codepen with a working example (the changes are starting with line 749).

The codepen has only the outer labels wrapped. I have left the inner labels for you to implement the approach described here. Good luck with that!